# Looking to recover draft from gmail in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

Gmail erased a draft I was writing on my cell. I know I open it on my computer but unfortunately it crashed and if I reopen Chrome it will ask to sync. I either wanted to fool Gmail to load offline and reach the draft or see if I can open local Chrome files to find it before I open Chrome again and overwrites the files.

Any advice on reaching this will be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can try your luck with this using a different browser.

Go to your Gmail and browse the drafts section or try typing "*in:draft*" instead of the search.

[image: example picture here]

So how are you going to use a browser without using a browser? Hmm...
You can download a browser installer to your phone and send it to your computer with a cable, or if you are using any linux distribution, you can type the following into the terminal. (for example ubuntu commands)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox -y
```

in  windows ? open your powershell or  windows terminal what u want

```
winget install -e --id Mozilla.Firefox
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: The OP asks how to access the Google Chrome temporary files stored in their computer, not the draft message stored in Google servers.